Terraform multi ternary condition
I have referred old questions but still not getting correct value for 'qa' environment.
For dev environment, it is giving correct value.
I have tried different ways but still not getting correct value for 'qa' environment.
For qa environment, it is giving value 'x' instead of expected value 'q'.
I didn't check for 'uat' and 'prod' environment cases and using this in locals.tf.
envsymbol = var.environment == "dev" ? "d" : (var.environment == "qa" ? "q") : (var.environment == "uat" ? "u" : "p")

envsymbol = var.environment == "dev" ? "d" : var.environment == "qa" ? "q" : var.environment == "uat" ? "u" : var.environment == "prod" ? "p" : "x"    
 
envsymbol = var.environment == "dev" ? "d" : (var.environment == "qa" ? "q" : (var.environment == "uat" ? "u" : (var.environment == "prod" ? "p" : "x")))
}

How to modify this to get correct value 'q' for 'qa' environment?

The easiest way is to use a map, rather than creating convoluted conditions:
variable "env" {
   default = {
     "prod": "p"
     "qa":   "q"
     "dev": "d"
   }
}

and then lookup:
envsymbol = lookup(var.env, var.environment, "x")


Certainly this is more readable and more elegant than using embed ternary operators, this does not explain why OP's code did not produce the expected output. The question was how to make that version working.

It seems to me that this answer is the solution to the OP's problem, even if he's asking something like what is wrong with my code?

Thanks, working

@naikum glad it worked. Accepting the answer would be appreciated.

IMO the aforementioned method is cleaner. But just an alternative answer, to make the expression shared in the question work, you need to use () properly. Match the following code with your expression and you will get your answer for, how to get correct value 'q' for 'qa' environment?
locals {

  envsymbol = (
    var.environment == "dev"
    ? "d"
    : (
      var.environment == "qa"
      ? "q"
      : (
        var.environment == "uat"
        ? "u"
        : "p"
      )
    )
  )

}

